# Avoid overriding members when inheriting

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I need to use C++. C++11 would be interesting, but I'd prefer without. I have the following class structure.

```
class Wheel { /*...*/ };
class MtbWheel : public Wheel { /*...*/ };

class Bike { Wheel front_wheel; };
class Mountainbike : public Bike { MtbWheel front_wheel; };
```

Now, this completely works: The Mountainbike overrides front_wheel, and thus can use an MtbWheel. Softwaretechnically, I am not happy, though.

- What I would prefer is disallowing to override front_wheel, or at least restrict overwriting by classes that do *not* inherit class Wheel.
- Instead of overriding front_wheel, I'd like only to "add" properties to it.

EDIT: Is there a solution without virtual functions, but with templates instead?

Comment: You are not overriding ``front_wheel``, you are hiding the ``front_wheel`` name.

Comment: You can't override member objects.

Comment: "Softwaretechnically" must be a term from TeutoniC++ :-)

Comment: I hide it? That's even worse, because I have Wheel and MTBWheel in Mountainbike, what a waste of memory?! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your  `front_wheel` member in `Mountainbike` class does **not** *override* `front_wheel`, it *hides* it. `Mountainbike` class actually has two `front_wheel` members, but the one from the `Bike` class is hidden by the one declared in `Mountainbike`. Meaning that if `Bike` accesses `front_wheel`, it will access an object of type `Wheel`, while when `Mountainbike` accesses `front_wheel`, it will access an object of type `MtbWheel` - but these two wheel objects don't know of each other!

Better OO design would be to make `front_wheel` e.g. a pointer in `Bike` (or even better a smart pointer), and initialize it in the constructor of `Mountainbike` to hold an object of a class derived from `Wheel` which fits best to `Mountainbike`. That way, when accessing front_wheel, one way or the other virtual functions come into play of course.

An alternative solution, as per Steve Jessop's suggestion in the comments below, making use of templates instead of using polymorphism, would be:

```
class Wheel { /*...*/ };
class MtbWheel : public Wheel { /*...*/ };

template <typename WheelType>
class Bike { WheelType front_wheel; };

class Mountainbike : public Bike<MtbWheel> { /* ... */ };
```

That way, no virtual functions are involved when operating on front_wheel. There are some points to consider with such a solution, however:

- For each different WheelType you use Bike with, separate code will be created; if you have many different such types, this might result in code bloat.
- If you have more than one class derived from `Bike` with different WheelType parameters, they **do not** have the same base class (see Steve Jessop's comment, and point 1), and therefore also can't be accessed polymorphically.
- You can not enforce an *explicit interface* on the `WheelType` being passed as template parameter to Bike; only the implicit interface is defined by the methods and members used from `Bike`. That should be no problem however, since the compiler can still verify that implicit interface.

Comment: Nice, but is there a method that uses templates instead of virtual functions?

Comment: @Johannes I'm not sure I understand what exactly you would want to do with templates? My proposed design doesn't use any virtual methods, by the way.

Comment: @Johannes: there is. It's called CRTP and it's a bit fiddly, but that's your search term. You could also do a simpler solution with templates that doesn't have all the features of CRTP, but avoids virtual functions by having `WheelType` as a template parameter of `Bike`. Then `MountainBike` inherits from `Bike<MTBWheel>`. Either way, note that `MountainBike` is using a *different* base class from what `PennyFarthing` would use: that may or may not sit well with your design so far.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: you don't mention any virtual functions, but if `Bike` is going to hold a (smart) pointer to type `Wheel`, and `MountainBike` is going to make that refer to an object of type `MTBWheel`, then in practice `Wheel` is going to need some virtual functions. Assuming `Wheel` has behavior that's different in `MTBWheel`, of course.

Comment: @SteveJessop thanks very much for your comments, I've updated my answer accordingly, hope everything's correct; oh and +1 for the PennyFarthing example, had to look up what that even is ;)

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks. But one question about point 2: What do you mean by "can't be accessed polymorphically"? You mean there is no function that could take both Bike and Mountainbike as a function parameter?

Comment: @Johannes Well you could write a template to take care of a method working for any Bike instantiation, but for each type a separate method would be created; but what I meant was more that you can't have a pointer or reference to Bike somewhere (in fact, what Bike template instantiation would you use?), and store Mountainbikes in it, or use virtual functions on it.

Comment: Think I'm getting it. I'll try to implement your solution now, thanks.

Comment: I have a strong issue :( Let's say I have ExtremeMountainbike and ExtremeMtbWheel, inheriting from Mountainbike and MtbWheel, respectively. Then ExtremeMountainbike can not use any functions of Mountainbike... Got a hint?

Comment: @Johannes I don't understand how you even *can* inherit from Mountainbike *and* use another wheel in my second example? You'd have to templatize Mountainbike as well or something, but then it gets ugly I guess... in the first one it's no problem since the ExtremeMountainbike would just create its own wheel type and store it in front_wheel. Take care however that you don't create front_wheel two times (once in Mtb once in ExtremeMtb); and ExtremeMtb could use functions from Mtb without any problems

Answer (score 1):

You're not overriding anything. There is still a `Wheel front_wheel;` in your derived class. You can access it through `m.Bike::front_wheel`, or something like that. If you want derived classes to provide their own instantiations of `front_wheel`, then you will need to only provide a `virtual` accessor in the base class and let derived classes create their own.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `front_wheel` is not overriden - it is just hidden. The member variable `Wheel front_wheel` is still in the `Mountainbike` class. So actually there are two variables named `front_wheel` in `Mountainbike`. But to access the hidden variable in `Mountainbike` you would need to say it explicitly: `Bike::front_wheel`.

A better way of doing what you want is to create an interface class with no data:

```
class Bike {
public:
  virtual Wheel const &getFronWheel() const = 0;
  virtual ~Bike() {}
};
```

and then derive any specific bike from that:

```
class RegularBike: public Bike {
public:
  virtual Wheel const &getFronWheel() const { return wheel; }
private:
  Wheel wheel;
}

class MtbBike: public Bike {
public:
  virtual MtbWheel const &getFronWheel() const { return wheel; }
private:
  MtbWheel wheel;
}
```

**Edit:** Without using virtuality, but templates instead:

```
template<typename WheelType>
class Bike {
public:
  /* Common methods for any bike...*/
protected: // or private
  WheelType wheel;
};
```

Then you can extend the Bike as you wish:

```
class RegularBike: public Bike<Wheel> {
   /* Special methods for regular bike...*/
};

class MtbBike: public Bike<MtbWheel> {
   /* Special methods for Mtb bike...*/
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing an example, but I am looking for a solutions without any virtual functions. I should have said that... :(

Comment: @Johannes: What is wrong with virtual functions? Anyway, I have added a solution without polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I've been looking for. I try to avoid virtual functions because of running time. My application needs to have a good runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a interface of IWheel instead of Class Wheel.

Create OverRide method in  MtbWheel class. So that whoever wants to override this method can override this method else use the default method which we have implemented in MtbWheel class. By using this you can add properties of it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not do that. Writing a derived class **requires** careful study of the base class, followed by careful design. Magic cookies are no substitute for knowledge and thought. And, yes, I've made my share of this kind of mistake, and kicked myself for being careless.

Comment: Not to do what exactly? Using template arguments? Which mistakes are you thinking of?

Comment: @Johannes - not accidentally hide names in base classes.